# Infinitely typing error

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm not sure if Google's login page, Chrome, or Mac OS caused this, but recently I encountered an error when trying to type my email into the Google login field of a webpage on my 1-day-old MacBook Pro (Mid 2014 edition). I typed "Ben." and it infinitely continued repeating to type it, ending up looking something like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
| .neB.neB.neB.neB.neB.neB.ne |
+-----------------------------+
```

**Has anyone else encountered this error?** [Google searches](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=infinitely%20repeating%20typing%20error) for it were fruitless, so I turn to SE.

---

This happened again in October 2015, under the same circumstances. Current Chrome is 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit). It continued to happen every several months under similar circumstances.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: It also reversed `Ben` to `neB`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, as if it were reading a buffer in reverse

Comment: @Ramhound I added the hardware to the question

Comment: Connected an external USB keyboard to your device.  Confirm if the problems surfaces with an external keyboard, if it doesn't, take it to your local Apple Store.

Comment: @Ramhound oh, maybe I didn't make it apparent that this only happened once and was cured by refreshing the page.

Comment: You made no mention that this only happened once.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I'm sorry about that; I should've.

Comment: I don't understand how Ramhound's first comment gets two upvotes. This doesn't look like a hardware problem at all. If it were hardware probably one character would repeat, not a string of characters, and they would surely not reverse their order. I call software bug.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hiccup with a web page that cannot be replicated and was fixed by refreshing the page.

Comment: @fixer1234 I forgot to update that it happens repeatedly, if rarely, every few months since posting